# regex javascript to look for a string with start and end pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would appreciate if someone can help me to come up with a regex that I can look for a pattern in a href. Pattern is to look for a query string hint=value& and then replace it with a new value hint=value2&. so the pattern should start with hint and end with & if there are more query strings or end of the value for hint.

I dont want to use jquery external library (purl). Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So why is [`str.replace("hint=value&", "hint=value2&")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) not enough?

Comment: I dont know the "value", it is one of the query string and the value can be anything

Comment: Right. But how do you know `value2`? Could you give some examples, on a string you want to match, and what you want to replace.

Comment: Here is the example of the url:                            https://www.sample.com/signup?es=click&hint=m%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2Ai%40gmail.com&ru=%2F" what I want is a regex to find hint=m%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2Ai%40gmail.com and replace it with hint=newstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead and check for `&` or the end of the string.

```
hint=(.*?)(?=&|$)
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/KLcrZQ/1)

Since we're using a lookahead, this means that the replacement doesn't need to include the `&` at the end. Which might be an important factor if `hint=value` were to be the last query element.

Which in JavaScript would look like this:

```js
const str = "https://www.sample.com/signup?es=click&hint=m%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2Ai%40gmail.com&ru=%2F%22";

const replacement = "hint=newstring";

const regex = /hint=(.*?)(?=&|$)/g;

const result = str.replace(regex, replacement);

console.log(result);
```

Given your example url, then `console.log(result)` would output:

```
https://www.sample.com/signup?es=click&hint=newstring&ru=%2F%22
```

Comment: thank you, it works. can you help me understand why different regex are working and which one is the accurate one? I am not good with regex at all :(

Comment: Take a look at the live preview, there's an in-depth explanation. However `(.*?)&` works, but it wouldn't work if `hint=value` is the last element in the query. Then you could do `(.*?)(&|$)` however now you need to add `&` to the end of the replacement if needed. This is why a lookahead `(?=&|$)` is best. Because here it just checks for the `&` but never captures it. Thus only replaces what is interesting to you, so to speak.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vallentin

Answer (score 0):

**Snippet:**

```
function replaceValue(newValue, url) {
    const regex = /\?.*?&((hint)=(.*)?&(.*))/g;
    const matches = regex.exec(url);
    let result = '';
    matches.forEach((matchString , index) => {
        if(index === 3) {
            result += newValue;
        }
        else {
            result += matchString;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

This would help you